# Collector current increases with Vcc in common emitter mode

Tags: bjt

I was analysing a simple common emitter bjt circuit when I found that the collector current was changing with changing Vcc even though collector current is independant of Vcc in theory .Why is this?
Is this a problem of my app or the throry means something else

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you provide us with the schematic circuit you are talking about?

Comment: `even though collector current is independant of Vcc in theory` that's true but what if the base current is changing with Vcc in your circuit? Show your circuit first, please. `Is this a problem of my app` And what app is this?

Comment: Please share a schematic of your circuit. You can use the schematic tool in the editor.

Comment: No - the collector current is not independent on Vcc. Which "theory" in which knowledge source are you referring to?